# Thing doesn't animate back

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, beginanimations

I want to animate and slowly dim the background when I bring up a picker. And then I want to slowly animate it back when I bring it down. For some reason it just works when I bring up the pickerView, not when a want to bring it down.

This code works:

```
-(IBAction)chooseCategory:(id)sender{
    [self.chooseCategoryView setHidden:NO];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    self.categoryPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 151, 320, 367);
    self.categoryPickerToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 106, 320, 45);
    self.pickerViewBackground.alpha = 0.6;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

But this doesn't

```
-(IBAction)hideCategory:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    self.pickerViewBackground.alpha = 0;
    self.categoryPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 545, 320, 367);
    self.categoryPickerToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, 320, 367);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.chooseCategoryView setHidden:YES];
    [self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Anyone knows why it doesn't?

Comment: just remove [self.chooseCategoryView setHidden:YES]; from hideCategory. It hides your view immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding the `categoryView` right after `commitAnimations`. So it will be hidden at the very beginning and you will not be able to see the animations.

You can either use the "old way" with `beginAnimations` etc. and use the `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` and hide the view there.

Or you use the up-to-date way by employing blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
 animations:^{
    // your animations
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
    // hide the view
 }];
```